# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, class

I want to establish a connection in my Model's class `__construct` and to be able to use it in child classes. But I'm getting an error "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object".

model.php

```
include('model/articlemodel.php');

class Model{
    protected $conn;
    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'KLAIDA: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

articlemodel.php

```
class ArticleModel extends Model{
    public function __construct(){
    }
    public function selectArticles(){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM txt_articles ORDER BY id DESC');
        $stmt->execute();

        $i = 0;
        $article_id = array();
        $article_title = array();
        $article_date = array();
        $article_content = array();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $article_id[i] = $row['id'];
            $article_title[i] = $row['title'];
            $article_date[i] = $row['date'];
            $article_content[i] = $row['content'];
            $i++;
        }

        return array($article_id, $article_title, $article_date, $article_content);
    }
}
```

After experimenting a bit I've noticed that the `conn` only works inside `__constructor`'s scope. Is there a way to establish a connection once inside a class and have it's child class run queries based on said connection?

Comment: Why the down vote? Was my question phrased incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the construct in the child class and hence the parent constructor is never called

So in the child class you need to do something as

```
public function __construct(){
   parent::__construct() ;
}
```

Comment: Either that, or don't override __construct() at all, especially as the ArticleModel constructor doesn't actually do anything at all here (beside prevent the parent constructor from running)

Comment: Exactly @MarkBaker if not not needed then it does not make sense to override the parent construct while dealing with connection. I remeber I had to do it in an abstract database class so as to connect to multiple databases. But the good part was the abstract class was designed to accept connection params as argument and I could send the DB settings via the constructor params.